# What's the difference between "xxx-compliant" and "xxx-compatible"?

Tags: terminology

I always see these phrases, what's the meaning and difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compliant with a standard or a spec.

Compatible with a piece of hardware or software.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer. +1 for being first :)

Comment: Well, what about this https://youtu.be/jAw7yWd5Gl8?si=nSXYaRoU9o7rs-4U&t=134 ?

Answer (score 7):

Compliant means it is working like it should as defined by some spec or standard or rules.

Compatible means it works, but not necessary setup as defined by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

For example, we had an issue with google ads in our company (has alot of in app ads) that weren't **compliant**(don't match all their rules) with their rules,
but were **compatible**(were working fine but not a must match their rules) and displaying well